# SQL Cross join to use max value for calculation in a case statement without group by

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I have the following table:

```
|BoreholeID|Mins|
-----------------
|BH1       |0.5 |
|BH1       |1   |
|BH1       |1.5 |
```

and i want to select a third column called timeline that has a case statement that returns either a 1 if the mins value is greater than 80% of the max mins value AND if the mins value is greater than the max mins value minus 5. I have the following query to do this:

```
select boreholeid, mins,
(case when mins < (max(max_query.maxts)*0.8) and
mins<(max(max_query.maxts)-5) then 1 else 0 end) as Timeline
from maxrawcalcs
cross join
(select max(maxrawcalcs.mins) maxts from maxrawcalcs) as max_query  
;
```

I have used a cross join in the past to use a max value like this and it worked no problem, but this query is telling me that i need to use a group by query for the other two selected fields which i do not want to do. How can i get around using a group by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used a nested SQL and kept your logic as the following :

```
select q.boreholeid, q.mins,
      (case when q.mins > ((q.maxts)*0.8) and
                 q.mins > ((q.maxts)-5) 
       then 1 else 0 
       end )         as Timeline
  from
(
select boreholeid, mins, 
       (select max(mins) maxts from maxrawcalcs) as maxts
  from maxrawcalcs
) q;

boreholeid  mins    Timeline
     BH1     0.5        0
     BH1      1         0
     BH1     1.5        1
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9009e/5)